# Query Related to Packet traversal in kernel

Tags: network-programming, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel

After reading the book "Understanding Linux Network internals".
I came to know about some concepts of how we get the packet from the network:-

```
>  When working in interrupt driven model, the nic registers an
>     interrupt handler;
>     • This interrupt handler will be called when a frame is received;
>     • Typically in the handler, we allocate sk buff by calling
>     dev alloc skb();
>     • Copies data from nic’s buffer to this struct just created;
>     • nic call generic reception routine netif rx();
>     • netif rx() put frame in per cpu queue;
>     • if queue is full, drop!
>     • net rx action() decision based on skb->protocol;
>     • This function basically dequeues the frame and delivery a copy
>     for every protocol handler;
>     • ptype all and ptype base queues
>     ip v4 rcv() will receive the ip datagram (if is a ipv4 packet);   
•ip checksum, check ip headers, ....   
• ip rcv finish() makes route decision (ip forward() or ip local delivery())
```

Now i had some queries related to it that are:-
Regarding netif_rx() code on the link http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/dev.c#L3075 which code says that it delivers the frame to upper layer

And regarding net_rx_action() http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/dev.c#L4041 which code says that it takes decision based on skb->protocol

And Whats the packet transmission process i mean when is the sk_buff allocated and all.

Please guide